# Find overlapping modularity in two graphs - iGraph in Python

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I have two related graphs created in iGraph, A and G. I find community in structure in G using either infomap or label_propagation methods (because they are two that allow for weighted, directional links). From this, I can see the modularity of this community for the G graph. However, I need to see what modularity this will provide for the A graph. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "related"? Same nodes but different links?

Comment: Yes. The two graphs have the same verteces. However, one of them is an "ally" graph, where links signify mutual aid, and one is an "enemy" graph, where links signify attacks. I want to use the ally graph (G) to get a community structure, then see if that correlates (or rather, anti-correlates) with the enemy graph (A) by seeing if there is a negative modularity.

Comment: In addition to my answer: you might also be interested in *correlation clustering* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_clustering), a problem more or less equivalent to community detection in signed graphs. It consists in finding a partition such that most positive links are inside the parts, and most negative ones are between the parts.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the `modularity` function?

```
im <- infomap.community(graph=G)
qG <- modularity(im)
memb <- membership(im)
qA <- modularity(x=A, membership=memb, weights=E(A)$weight)
cat("qG=",qG," vs. qA=",qA,"\n",sep="")
```

Note: tested with igraph v0.7, I don't have a more recent version right now. The parameter/function names might slightly differ.

Comment: I know this is old, but this is an answer for R, not python.

Answer (score -1):

So I figured it out. What you need to do is find a community structure, either pre-defined or using one of the methods provided for community detection, such as infomap or label_propagation. This gives you a vertex clustering, which you can use to place on another graph and from that use .q to find the modularity.

Comment: I would show your code to make this more helpful for people in the future.